# How to constantly update a variable (using a spinbox with tkinter)?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have in my program two spinboxes, created with tkinter. I want the variables chosen by the user to be added to a list, so I can use those values later in the program. The problem I'm currently having is that the values are stored just once in the list, and I don't manage to update them, despite all of the things I tried. To be clear, I just want two values in the list, so when the user select another number, it will replace the proper value stored in the list.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
from tkinter import *

windowTk = Tk()
pwMain = PanedWindow(windowTk, orient=VERTICAL)
pwTop = PanedWindow(pwMain, orient=HORIZONTAL)

def configTables() :

    sLine = Spinbox(pwTop, from_=0, to=15)
    pwTop.add( Label(pwTop, text = "Combien y a-t-il de lignes de table ?") )
    pwTop.add( sLine )

    sColumn = Spinbox(pwTop, from_=0, to=15)
    pwTop.add( Label(pwTop, text = "Combien y a-t-il de colonnes de tables ?") )
    pwTop.add( sColumn )

    pwTop.pack()

    pwMain.pack()

    global coordTables
    coordTables = []
    coordTables.append( int(sLine.get()) )
    coordTables.append( int(sColumn.get()) )
    return coordTables


print( configTables() )
windowTk.mainloop()
```

I hope my request is understandable, so you can help me.

Thank you

LoneRetrievr

**UPDATE** : I tried the following code, and it works, but nothing appears in the window (tkinter's window remains white).

```
from tkinter import *

windowTk = Tk()
pwMain = PanedWindow(windowTk, orient=VERTICAL)
pwTop = PanedWindow(pwMain, orient=HORIZONTAL)

lines = IntVar(windowTk, value=0)
columns = IntVar(windowTk, value=0)

def configTables() :

    sLine = Spinbox(pwTop, from_=0, to=15, textvariable=lines)
    pwTop.add( Label(pwTop, text = "Combien y a-t-il de lignes de tables ?") )
    pwTop.add( sLine )

    sColumn = Spinbox(pwTop, from_=0, to=15, textvariable=columns)
    pwTop.add( Label(pwTop, text = "Combien y a-t-il de colonnes de tables ?") )
    pwTop.add( sColumn )

    pwTop.pack()
    pwMain.pack()

numberLines = lines.get()
numberColumns = columns.get()
print( numberLines, numberColumns )
windowTk.mainloop()
```

I know it will print just once the values and that's what I want it to do.
Can you help me ? I think it's very simple, but I don't find where's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IntVar` to connect the spin boxes to Python variables. I have extended your program with an example. It adds a button to print the current value of the spin boxes:

```
from tkinter import *

windowTk = Tk()
pwMain = PanedWindow(windowTk, orient=VERTICAL)
pwTop = PanedWindow(pwMain, orient=HORIZONTAL)
lignes = IntVar(windowTk, value=0)
colonnes = IntVar(windowTk, value=0)

def print_vars():
    print(lignes.get(), colonnes.get())

def configTables() :

    sLine = Spinbox(pwTop, from_=0, to=15, textvariable=lignes)
    pwTop.add( Label(pwTop, text = "Combien y a-t-il de lignes de table ?") )
    pwTop.add( sLine )

    sColumn = Spinbox(pwTop, from_=0, to=15, textvariable=colonnes)
    pwTop.add( Label(pwTop, text = "Combien y a-t-il de colonnes de tables ?") )
    pwTop.add( sColumn )

    pwTop.pack()

    b = Button(pwMain, text='print', command=print_vars)
    b.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    pwMain.pack()

    global coordTables
    coordTables = []
    coordTables.append( int(sLine.get()) )
    coordTables.append( int(sColumn.get()) )
    return coordTables


print( configTables() )
windowTk.mainloop()
```

Note, I have not removed things which are no longer necessary, like `coordTables` variable and the return statement.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried something but I have a problem.

Comment: @LoneRetriever Your order of operations is wrong. You cannot access the IntVars before running tk's mainloop. You have to do this while the event loop is running. Why do you want to move away from the solution? It seems you have some structure of application in your mind which you don't tell in the question.

Answer (score 0):

this is what you would want to do, I believe.

I suggest you an object oriented approach.

Tkinter has IntVar() and other variables very powerfull.

```
import tkinter as tk
```

class App(tk.Frame):

```
def __init__(self,):

    super().__init__()

    self.master.title("Hello World")
    self.lines = tk.IntVar()
    self.columns = tk.IntVar()
    self.coordTables = []
    self.init_ui()

def init_ui(self):

    self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=1,)

    f = tk.Frame()

    tk.Label(f, text = "Combien y a-t-il de lignes de tables ?").pack()
    tk.Spinbox(f, from_=0, to=15, textvariable= self.lines).pack()

    tk.Label(f, text = "Combien y a-t-il de colonnes de tables ?").pack()
    tk.Spinbox(f, from_=0, to=15, textvariable= self.columns).pack()

    w = tk.Frame()

    tk.Button(w, text="Print", command=self.on_callback).pack()
    tk.Button(w, text="Reset", command=self.on_reset).pack()
    tk.Button(w, text="Close", command=self.on_close).pack()

    f.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)
    w.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=0)


def on_callback(self,):
    args = (self.lines.get(),self.columns.get())
    self.coordTables.append(args)

    print ("Numers of coords: {0}".format(len(self.coordTables)))

    for e,i in self.coordTables:
        print(e,i)

def on_reset(self):
    self.lines.set(0)
    self.columns.set(0)
    self.coordTables = []

def on_close(self):
    self.master.destroy()
```

if **name** == '**main**':

`app = App()
   app.mainloop()`